# setText() doesn't change my textView()

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, textview

I try to show a text that I receive from a bluetooth device.
I receive the text, I change it to a string, I can show it in Logcat, but it doesn't appear in my textView...
I tried different ways like place the setText() just after receiving the message, but nothing works... Any idea ?

My Function:

```
package com.example.blueconnect;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    BluetoothAdapter blueAdapter = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        blueAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (blueAdapter == null) {
            Log.e("Error","The device has no Bluetooth.");  
        }
        else{
            if (!blueAdapter.isEnabled()) blueAdapter.enable();
        }

        //Do the Bluetooth visible
        /*Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
        */
        //Start the server
        AcceptThread blueNect = new AcceptThread();
        blueNect.start();
    }

     private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
            // The local server socket
            private BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

            public AcceptThread() {
            }

            public void run() {         
                BluetoothSocket socket = null;
                BluetoothAdapter mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                String lineRead = "";

                // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
                while (true) {

                    try {
                        //récupération de l'élément
                        TextView tvPD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPD);
                        Log.i("MESSAGE",lineRead);
                        tvPD.setText(lineRead);

                        // Create a new listening server socket
                        Log.d("TAG", ".....Initializing RFCOMM SERVER....");

                        // MY_UUID is the UUID you want to use for communication
                        mmServerSocket = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("ServeurBluetooth", UUID.fromString("30fa7085-2927-4f90-8da7-b9a86c398373"));                    
                        //mmServerSocket = mAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);  you can also try using In Secure connection...

                        // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                        // successful connection or an exception                    
                        socket = mmServerSocket.accept();                   


                    } catch (Exception e) { }

                    try {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Closing Server Socket.....");                    
                        mmServerSocket.close();

                        InputStream tmpIn = null;
                        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

                        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams

                        tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                        tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();

                        DataInputStream mmInStream = new DataInputStream(tmpIn);
                        DataOutputStream mmOutStream = new DataOutputStream(tmpOut); 


                        //Read message
                        BufferedReader bReader2=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mmInStream));
                        lineRead=bReader2.readLine();
                        Log.i("MESSAGE",lineRead);

                      //send response to spp client
                        PrintWriter pWriter=new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(mmOutStream));
                        pWriter.write("Response String from SPP Server\r\n");
                        pWriter.flush();
                        Log.d("TAG", "Respond sent to the CLient");

                        pWriter.close();

                        // here you can use the Input Stream to take the string from the client whoever is connecting
                        //similarly use the output stream to send the data to the client
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //catch your exception here
                    }

                }
            }

        }
}
```

My xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/header" />

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPD"
            style="@style/TitleText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Devices" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope you could help me...

Comment: where do you call `run()`?

Comment: whose **run()** method is this ?

Comment: Where and when do you set lineRead?

Comment: I posted my entire code, maybe it could help you.

Comment: @Underground72 just as i suspected. you cannot update ui from a background thread. you need to update ui on the ui thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tvPD.setText(lineRead);
```

`lineRead` is initialized to `""` and never modified. That's why your `TextView` shows always nothing.

Edit: you are inside a `Thread` different from the `UI Thread`  and  all the modifications to UI Elements should be done on the `UI Thread`. you have to use an `Handler` or `runOnUiThread`

Comment: @Underground72 move tvPD.setText(lineRead); after Log.i("MESSAGE",lineRead);

Comment: @E.Odebugg can you reprhase ? What should I move, where and why ?

Comment: @E.Odebugg how does that make any difference? after initialization you can settext to textview.

Comment: @Raghunandan he says on the comments that he gets the read value from the bluetooth after the try statement begins. So if he calls setText after that the value is  stored on lineRead, he will see it on the TextView. I said "after Log.i("MESSAGE",lineRead);" because he says he sees the Log so I know that lineRead has the value after this point

Comment: @E.Odebugg the snippet is inside an infinite while loop

Comment: also two try blocks the second one just to log info. not required.

Comment: Yes, my lineRead is changed at the end, where I put the comment. And the LogCat after show it well, like the LogCat before the setText().

Comment: @blackbelt I agree that your solution is correct (I +1'd it). I just wanted Underground72 to try moving setText(lineRead) to see if he could see the value on the TextView

Comment: @blackbelt the setText() is inside my infinite loop, it should change.
Can you take a look at the post I edited please..

Comment: Thanks @blackbelt, I tried with a runOnUiThread and it works ! 
Do you know why it worked anyway with a string like "hello" in the setText() ?

Answer (score 0):

there is a mistake in lineread in your textview your write lineRead

change this code:

```
   Log.i("MESSAGE", lineread);       
   tvPD.setText(lineRead);
```

by:

```
   Log.i("MESSAGE", lineread);       
   tvPD.setText(lineread);
```

i hope that helps you

Comment: no its capital `R` only. @blackbelt is right. see this `String lineRead = "";`

Comment: bit the variable that he logs does not exist... there is only `lineRead` and no `lineread` so it shouldn't even compile or it is a typo in the pasted code